# Find out physical memory mapping

Tags: ubuntu, linux-kernel, memory

I want to debug a memory problem systematically.

My system setup is as follows: I have a (physical) server with 2 CPUs (each with multiple cores). Each CPU has 1 TiB of RAM (16 memory modules with 64 GiB each) connected to its memory controllers. So, in total, the system has 2 TiB of RAM. Currently, I use Ubuntu 20.04 as operating system on that server.

When I execute `lsmem --output-all` as root, I get the following output:

```
RANGE                                  SIZE  STATE REMOVABLE    BLOCK NODE  ZONES
0x0000000000000000-0x00000000ffffffff    4G online       yes      0-1    0   None
0x0000000100000000-0x000000fcffffffff 1008G online       yes    2-505    0 Normal
0x0000010000000000-0x000001007fffffff    2G online       yes      512    0   None
0x0000010080000000-0x000001ffffffffff 1022G online       yes 513-1023    1 Normal
0x0000020000000000-0x000002007fffffff    2G online       yes     1024    1   None

Memory block size:         2G
Total online memory:       2T
Total offline memory:      0B
```

As you can see, the kernel "splits" the memory into blocks of 2 GiB, which is to be expected on a system with this amount of RAM. However, I find it odd that only 1019 blocks are listed (it should be 1024 blocks). 5 blocks (10 GiB of memory) from node 0 seem to be missing. (I have other servers with 2 TiB of memory as well, and I do not encounter this behavior on them.)

I am wondering what happened to these 10 GiB. Even if this memory is used by some device, it should be listed when doing a `lsmem --output-all`. In fact, `cat /proc/iomem` does not list the missing memory blocks either. It is as if the 10 GiB didn't even exist.

**So here is my question:** Is there a way to find out the mapping from the blocks (as listed by `lsmem --output-all`) to physical memory (i.e. to the RAM module)? This would be very helpful, because then I could change the effected RAM module to see if there is a physical problem with that module.

**I already tried** looking through `/sys/devices/system/edac/mc`, and I found the memory controllers and the memory ranks in there, but I didn't find out to which blocks the memory is mapped.

Answer (score 0):

Some of the total memory is reserved for the system itself. So the available memory you see on Linux is the memory that is leftover. The 5 blocks ought to be the reserved memory from your system.

With `dmidecode --type memory` you can list how much physical ram you have installed.

With `sudo grep '^[^ ]' /proc/iomem` you can list what blocks of memory are reserved for the system.

[Source](https://toroid.org/linux-physical-memory)

Comment: Thank you for taking the time in trying to answer my question! I know about `dmidecode --type memory` and also about `/proc/iomem`. You are right, memory can be reserved by the system, and commands such as `free` don't show it in this case. But it is my understanding that even reserved memory is shown with `lsmem`. So I guess it is some kind of hardware defect, and therefore it would be nice to know the mapping between the addresses that the kernel uses and the RAM modules.